# Retrieve data from table2 using column names stored in table1

Tags: sql-server

I want to be able to look up fields values from a secondary table that stores the secondary table field names as strings in a primary table.

I am trying to both query the primary table itself to get the field names I want from the secondary table:

How can I use that string that contains the field name to select data from table2,  given the id of a specific row.

The use case here, is that table1 also contains a note field.  I want to populate that note field with the contents of a specific record in table2.  I want to do this for all the  records in table 1: each record references a different field by field name.

Another way to look at this:
Table2 has 1 row we want data from, and we know the ID
table1 stores the list of fields that we need data for from table 2
How do I get both pieces of data (field name, and field value) using these constraints?

all data is varchar

table1

| fieldname | externalID |
| --- | --- |
| myField1 | 001 |
| myField2 | 001 |

table2

| id | myField1 | myField2 | myField3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | myField1ValueForID001 | myField2ValueForID001 | myField3ValueForID001 |
| 002 | moredata1 | moredata2 | moredata3 |

```sql
select fieldname,
(select [fieldname] from table2 where id = ) as fieldData
from table1
```

result

| fieldname | fieldData |
| --- | --- |
| myField1 | myField1 |
| myField2 | myField2 |

desired result

| fieldname | fieldData |
| --- | --- |
| myField1 | myField1ValueForID001 |
| myField2 | myField2ValueForID001 |

Comment: Data in an understandable format will help us help you. Posting it as DDL and DML would be best, but at least well formatted tabular `text`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `CASE` expression, though I do recommend you rethink your design here:

```sql
SELECT *
INTO dbo.Table1
FROM (VALUES('myField1','001'),
            ('myField2','001'))V(FieldName,ExternalID);

SELECT *
INTO dbo.Table2
FROM (VALUES('001','myField1ValueForID001','myField2ValueForID001','myField3ValueForID001'),
            ('002','moredata1','moredata2','moredata3'))V(id,myField1,myField2,myField3);
GO

SELECT T1.FieldName,
       CASE T1.FieldName WHEN 'myField1' THEN T2.myField1
                         WHEN 'myField2' THEN T2.myField2
                         WHEN 'myField3' THEN T2.myField3
       END AS FieldData
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
     JOIN dbo.Table2 T2 ON T1.ExternalID = T2.id;

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.Table1;
DROP TABLE dbo.Table2;
```